# How to map routes to modules without the use of multiple Sinatra apps?

Tags: ruby, web, routes, sinatra

I have this structure:

```
 module Analytics
    def self.registered(app)

      module DepartmentLevel
        departmentParticipation = lambda do
        end
        departmentStatistics = lambda do
        end

        app.get '/participation', &departmentParticipation
      end

      module CourseLevel
        courseParticipation = lambda do
        end
      end
    end
```

And at the end of the module Analytics I would like to route each piece of the request to his specific subModule. If it is requested

```
'analytics/department'
```

it should redirect to the module DepartmentLevel which has its own routes as

```
app.get 'participation', &departmentParticipation
```

I first thought on using **map**. But how to use it without having to **run** a new or inherit Sinatra::Base object?

Comment: Not sure you can... Can you explain why Map does not work for you?

Comment: @Manuel, map works for me... but I wanted to work without having to **run** a new class inherited from Sinatra::Base. After a while struggling with this I realized that I could simple manage the route and subroutes with module variables named as @@current_root_path and @@current_directory_path, for example. By the name I think you can get what I mean... But I also realized that doing so made me lose readability. At the end I am looking for a approach similar to the answer given by you: subclassing. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need, but here's how I build my modular Sinatra apps: By using `use`

First, I have my `ApplicationController`. It's the base class for all other Controllers. It lives in `controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  # some settings that are valid for all controllers
  set :views, File.expand_path('../../views', __FILE__)
  set :public_folder, File.expand_path('../../public', __FILE__)
  enable :sessions

  # Helpers
  helpers BootstrapHelpers
  helpers ApplicationHelpers
  helpers DatabaseHelpers

  configure :production do
    enable :logging
  end
end
```

Now, all other Controllers/Modules inherit from `ApplicationController`. Example `controllers/website_controller.rb`:

require 'controllers/application_controller'

```
class WebsiteController < ApplicationController
  helpers WebsiteHelpers

  get('/') { slim :home }
  get('/updates') { slim :website_updates }
  get('/test') { binding.pry; 'foo' } if settings.development?
end
```

At last, in `app.rb` is where it all comes together:

```
# Require some stuff
require 'yaml'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require 'logger'

# Require own stuff
APP_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift APP_ROOT
require 'lib/core_ext/string'
require 'controllers/application_controller.rb'

# Some Run-Time configuration...
ApplicationController.configure do
  # DB Connections, Logging and Stuff like that
end

# Require ALL models, controllers and helpers
Dir.glob("#{APP_ROOT}/{helpers,models,controllers}/*.rb").each { |file| require file }

# here I glue everything together
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  use WebsiteController
  use OtherController
  use ThingController

  not_found do
    slim :'404'
  end
end
```

With this Setup, all I need to do in `config.ru` is

```
require './app.rb'
run MyApp
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you,  @Manuel. It help me a lot! I used your approach, but adding subroutes in MyApp, for example,  which was what I was looking for. Thanks!